# Saleor Django SQL errors on Windows 10//eCommerce

Tags: django, cmd, e-commerce, secret-key, saleor

I have this problem for a few days now, and I can't solve it. I have red all the docs and files and did everything as instructed. So basically, I've installed Django latest ver, installed Python 3.x also the latest ver, and wanted to implement Saleor and work on a new e commerce web app.

Gone to Saleor Win installation Docs (official), installed all the required apps like SQL, Git etc. And got no errors. Of course, I did all of that via vurtualenv which I placed in the separated folder. So I have>Project>ecommerce and myvenv folders inside.

I placed saleor in ecommerce. The problem starts when I try to do Python manage.py migrate > I get a `SECRET_KEY` error. And my question is, how to define a secret key on Windows cmd?
And next question is about installing SQL. It seems that I just CAN'T define new db using cmd on Windows. This just keeps giving me nightmares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SECRET_KEY` should be set as any other environmental variable.

I think this one might be helpful:
http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/

Comment: Solved: Just needed to put SECRET_KEY variable into settings.py

Comment: You should not keep `SECRET_KEY` directly in your `settings.py`, that's what the env variable is for